# append multiple excels into a single excel placed inside a folder using python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have multiple excels having same number of column name. I want to append all the excels into a single excel file. I have the below code where I am getting the output. Only the problem is that I am not getting its header/Title/first row (which is same column names in all excel files). My code is as below :

````
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

output = pd.DataFrame()
for file in glob.glob(os.getcwd()+"\\*.xlsx"):
    cn = pd.read_excel(file)
    output = output.append(cn)
output.to_excel(os.getcwd()+"\\outPut.xlsx", index = False, na_rep = "NA", header=None)
print("Completed +::" )```
````

Comment: The header=None parameter means that you do NOT want the header. Just drop it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `header=True`

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

output = pd.DataFrame()
for file in glob.glob(os.getcwd()+"\\*.xlsx"):
    cn = pd.read_excel(file)
    output = output.append(cn)
output.to_excel(os.getcwd()+"\\outPut.xlsx", index = False, na_rep = "NA", header=True)
print("Completed +::" )
```